# The format of the input string is incorrect

Tags: c#, winforms, constructor

I get the error message

> The format of the input string is incorrect.

```
 public partial class Fiche_Ordre : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
    {
        public string ClientID = "", OderId = "", TempId = "";
       .....

        public Fiche_Ordre()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Constuct_Page();

        }

        public Fiche_Ordre(string OrderID)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Constuct_Page();

            Pers_Ordre oPersOrdr = oOrder_BL.Get_OrdreOne_BL(ClientID, Convert.ToInt32(OderId), false);
            textEdit_RaisonSoc.Text = oPersOrdr.RaisonSoc;
        }
```

when I call the constuctor from other form:

```
 private void GoToFiche(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {                              
                Fiche_Ordre f_Fiche = new Fiche_Ordre("1");
               // Fiche_Ordre f_Fiche = new Fiche_Ordre(gridView_Liste_Ordres.GetRowCellValue(0, "NO_ORDRE").ToString());
                f_Fiche.Show();
            }
            catch (Exception excThrown)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(excThrown.Message);          
            }
```

I have constructor:  `public Fiche_Ordre(string OrderID)`

Comment: What line are you getting the error on? I suspect it is not on any of the bits of code you posted.

Comment: Because `OderId` is set to "". You're not using the right variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 public Fiche_Ordre(string OrderID)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Constuct_Page();

            Pers_Ordre oPersOrdr = oOrder_BL.Get_OrdreOne_BL(ClientID, Convert.ToInt32(OderId), false);
            textEdit_RaisonSoc.Text = oPersOrdr.RaisonSoc;
        }
```

You are passing `OrderID` and using `OderId`.

Watch your case and spelling.